# What django template filter to use for embedding css in a style tag

Tags: django, filter, django-templates

I have a template where I need to embed some CSS from a model within a style tag, like this:

```
<style>{{m.get_css_text}}</style>
```

(in case it matters, m is actually a for-in var)

This works without a problem except for one glitch which only happens in IE. I have a rule in the CSS includes a filter rule, which uses quotes, like this -

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#f5f5f5") !important;
```

The default escaping behavior of django escapes the quotes, and this breaks the CSS rule, which mucks up the CSS in IE, where the rule applies.

Using the |safe filter solves this problem, of course, but I would rather not use it. For now the model holding the CSS is only editable by my staff, but in the future this could be created by our users.

My question is this - what filter(s) should I use to prevent escaping of quotes etc. but to keep the tag safe? My only idea so far is to use the removetags filter, but I'm not sure it's the best idea.

Thanks!

Comment: You could avoid this problem by doing something like `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#{{m.startColor}}", endColorstr="#{{endColor}}") !important;, so that data is not mixed with`the html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, for now I have to keep the entire set of CSS rules as a text blob, so I cannot do this.

Comment: You can try alternating betwen single quotes `'` in your variable text and double quote `"` in the templates as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a combo of `striptags` and `safe`, i.e.:

```
<style>{{m.get_css_text|striptags|safe}}</style>
```

With HTML tags removed, there's nothing "unsafe" about `safe` (sorry, couldn't help myself).